# when this message come - App is Actively Using your location, UI Changes

Tags: ios, ios11, background-application

The screen in which the message comes on the top side which display as - app is actively using your location.

[image]

Main issue is what I have faced when this come when my app is in the background, and I open any other app, what i see is that the UI moves to bottom side.

This issue comes only in ios 11.2.1.

Comment: What UI moves? Do you have a screen of the layout?

Comment: Image of screen is missing

Comment: screen : please click on it

Comment: IF an other app is not complying with SafeArea, that's not really your problem, isn't it?

Comment: This is my problem when I close the app, and move to any other app, over that opened app I found this message on the top which is ok for me , but the UI of that screen Changes - that's my problem.

Comment: This happens when your app asks for location `only in use` and it goes background while still under execution. Are you using auto layout ? If so, you should look your constraints and safe are to avoid this behaviour

Comment: yes I have used the auto layout with safe area, which is proper I guess.